# Linq Syntax issue

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some issues with a bit of LINQ syntax and I believe I'm missing something very simple here.

I've got a basic class defined as:

```
public class ParseData
{
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string AssociatedCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of these class items that will be processed:

```
public ObservableCollection<ParseData> OffsetList { get; set; }
```

I have a method that queries this collection to see if there are any entries that match a particular criteria and based on whether or not any do, will process the items involved differently.

Here's the syntax I'm using (LINQ syntax first in while loop):

```
private void ParseText()
{
     //Prep code for while loop
    while (currentSpacePosition != -1)
    {
        var possibleOffset = OffsetList.Where(offset => offset.Offset.Equals(currentCursorPosition)).ToList<ParseData>();
        nextCursorPosition = currentSpacePosition + 1;
        currentTextBlock = Text.Substring(currentCursorPosition,(currentSpacePosition - currentCursorPosition) + 1);
        if (possibleOffset.Count != 0)
        {
            //Process one way;
            AddHyperlinkButton(currentTextBlock);
        }
        else
        {
                       //Process another way.
            AddTextBlock(currentTextBlock);
        }
        currentCursorPosition = nextCursorPosition;
        currentSpacePosition = Text.IndexOf(' ', currentCursorPosition);
    }
    //More processing
}
```

What am I missing here?  The poosibleOffset variable keeps returning an empty list, though if I step through the code, there is an an item in the OffsetList that contains an offset prerty that will meet my criteria for selection, which suggest that my syntax isn't correct when trying to check values.

If you need more code or information about the process, I'll be happy to provide it.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: Why don't you just write (offset => offset.Offset == currentCursorPosition)? No need for `Equals`.

Comment: Put some curly braces around your if/else blocks. It appears as though you have two statements you want in your else, but only the first will be there.

Comment: Ryan's right... its not clear if there is one or two statements under the else branch (comments not counted)

Comment: Sorry about the cut & paste mixup.  Added braces for clarity.

Comment: Your code looks slightly inefficient, but correct. I would be inclined to write this "var query = from offset in OffsetList where offset.Offset.Equals(currentCursorPosition) select offset; bool hasMatch = query.Any();" This style runs the query only until the first result is found; your style runs the query to find all the results, builds a list, and then counts it. If all you care about is whether there is something that matches your criterion, then just ask whether there is any match.  Why you're not getting any results at all, I don't know; we'd need more info.

Comment: Eric, you are correct.  I arrived at this syntax because I started having trouble with the other.  If you look at my answer below, you'll see that I was the major issue in this equation and after resolving that I reverted to exactly the sytax you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ladies and gentlemen, please allow me to apologize for wasting your valuable time.  I however, am a massive idiot.  In the process of debugging some issues, I commented out the code that initialized the property OffsetList, which was the key element in my search criteria.  Had I noticed this earlier, the LINQ query would have worked the first time out of the gate.

Thanks to all of you who tried to save me from my own stupidity.  I will leave the question up for a short while so that you can all point and laugh, then I will close.

Comment: I'm sure all of us have made equally stupid mistakes - it doesn't make you any more of an idiot than the rest of us!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your use of Linq really:

```
    public class ParseData
    {
        public int Offset { get; set; } 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ParseData> OffsetList { get; set; }

    public Program()
    {
        OffsetList = new ObservableCollection<ParseData> { new ParseData { Offset = 5 } };
        int offset = 5;
        int found = OffsetList.Where(o => o.Offset.Equals(offset)).ToList().Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Found: " + found);
    }
```

Output:

```
Found: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into "access to modified closure" issue. You need to copy currentSpacePosition into a local temporary variable prior to Where Clause and then use that within the where criteria.

Comment: I don't think so... he's ToList-ing it, which should trip enumeration prior to currentCursorPosition is changed...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell me what is the type of **currentCursorPosition** variable?
For example, if it is of long type compiler will choose to use Equals(object) overload of Int32 and in this case it returns false even if the variable has mathematically equal value to the one in Offset property.